# Launch Windows Photos app from C++ for a list of files

Tags: c++, winapi, photos

I want to launch the Windows Photos app from C++ for a list of image files.

Problem with Photos app is that, if it is launched using ShellExecute (for a single file) it disables the next and previous buttons, even if the folder contains other images.

I have tried using IApplicationActivationManager COM interface to launch the photos app

IApplicationActivationManager->ActivateApplication is launching the app without any file, but IApplicationActivationManager->ActivateForFile is failing with error: **0x80270255 - This app has mulitple extensions registered to support the specified contract. Activation by AppUserModelId is ambiguous.**

Is there a way to launch the app with list of files or launch the app first and then send the list of files to open.

Comment: Please show the code that fails.