# Programmatically open image in Photos app with previous & next arrows enabled

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, photo, explorer

When I navigate to a directory and double click an image, it opens with Windows' Photos app (my default application). I can then scroll to the next or previous images with the scroll wheel or the arrows on either side of the window.

However, if I open an image from the explorer's search results, I cannot scroll to the next/previous image. Neither can I when I open an image programmatically. How can I open an image programmatically in Windows' Photo app so that it will allow me to scroll to the next/previous images?

I remember reading that, when opening from a folder, explorer passes the directory as an extra argument. I have not found any documentation on how exactly that happens. I have tried to replicate this programmatically (in Python) with no success. I have tried combinations such as:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen('D:/path/img05.jpg', shell=True)                # Test 1
subprocess.Popen(['D:/path/img05.jpg', 'D:/path'], shell=True)   # Test 2
subprocess.Popen(['D:/path', 'D:/path/img05.jpg'], shell=True)   # Test 3
subprocess.Popen('D:/path/img05.jpg', shell=True, cwd='D:/path') # Test 4
```

Some notes:

- `shell=True` --> With this, the executable is the explorer. It will then choose the default application for the file.
- I'm already being careful about spaces in paths by using double quotes: `'"D:/path to image/img05.jpg"'`
- This is specific to Photos app. Other image viewers (e.g. HoneyView) handle the problem correctly.
- [Similar unresolved question for C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50251213/launch-windows-photos-app-from-c-for-a-list-of-files).

Comment: Explorer does not pass the folder as an argument. One of the PowerToys use the folder, you can check their source...

Comment: Thanks. I've looked over them but I don't recognize this feature in any of them. Do you remember which one?

Comment: No I don't, perhaps I'm remembering it incorrectly and it is some other Microsoft tool. The MS Photo viewer knows about the folder at least back to XP which may be easier to debug without any UWP junk. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65064308/getting-the-sorting-order-of-a-folder-as-defined-in-windows-explorer is somewhat related as a similar method is required to get the sort column of the folder. Raymond Chen commented on a similar question here on SO but I'm unable to find it right now...

Comment: At https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71365499/how-to-get-a-complete-explorer-listing-related-to-a-file-used-to-launch-an-assoc Raymond says `FileActivatedEventArgs.NeighboringFilesQuery` but there has to be some other solution because Photo Viewer did it before this existed...

Answer (score 0):

Below is my solution/workaround to open an image programmatically, in Python, with the ability to browse the image collection linked to the open image directory.

```py
import os
import time
import pyautogui

dir = 'D:/path/'
item_position = 5 - 1

# Open directory where is the image D:/path/img05.jpg.
os.system(f'start {dir}')
time.sleep(0.05)
if item_position == 0:
    # Handle case of the first item.
    pyautogui.press('down')
    pyautogui.press('up')
else:
    # Press the down key to reach the image position.
    pyautogui.press('down', presses=item_position)

# Open the image pressing enter key.
pyautogui.press('enter')
```

> **Note:**
>
> - Microsoft Photos app should be set as default application to open the targeted file.
> - This will be useful in the case you know the position of the image to open, in the file explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10/11 UWP Photo viewer require 'FileActivatedEventArgs.NeighboringFilesQuery' options to display previous / next button.

before (launch using command line or ShellExecute function)
[image: no button at photo viewer]
after (launch using UWP api with 'NeighboringFilesQuery')
[image: button are visible when set 'NeighboringFilesQuery']

sample code (c++)

```
BOOL LaunchImageViewer(LPCWSTR imagePath) {
    BOOL re = FALSE;
    winrt::Windows::Storage::Search::QueryOptions queryOp(winrt::Windows::Storage::Search::CommonFolderQuery::DefaultQuery);
    winrt::Windows::Storage::StorageFolder parentFolder = NULL;
    winrt::Windows::Storage::StorageFile file = NULL;
    winrt::Windows::System::LauncherOptions launchOp;
    
    if (!path) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (GetFileAttributesW(path) == INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES) {
        OutputDebugStringW(L"File not found\n");
        return FALSE;
    }

    LPWSTR parentPath = __GetParentPath(path);
    if (!parentPath) {
        goto escapeArea;
    }

    parentFolder = winrt::Windows::Storage::StorageFolder::GetFolderFromPathAsync(parentPath).get();
    if (!parentFolder) {
        goto escapeArea;
    }

    //This is important!!
 
launchOp.NeighboringFilesQuery(parentFolder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(queryOp));

    file = winrt::Windows::Storage::StorageFile::GetFileFromPathAsync(path).get();
    if (!file) {
        goto escapeArea;
    }

    re = winrt::Windows::System::Launcher::LaunchFileAsync(file, launchOp).get();

    escapeArea:

    free(parentPath);
    return re;
}
```

Full codes are available in here
(https://github.com/bho3538/OpenWindowsPhotoViewer)